# how to print multiple lines with a random element in it in Perl

Tags: perl, for-loop

I want to output a list file using Perl. Within that list file I need to have 10,000+ lines, such as

```
abc -s 1234 
abc -s 2345
```

The numbers in the above statements could be random, but with a range (say upto a million). I don't want to write 10,000 lines, is there a simpler way to do this?

Can I use a for statement here, but I am not sure about how to generate random numbers to print within the statement.

Eg;

```
for (i=1; i<= 10000; i++) {
    print "abc -s &rand()\n";
}
```

Is this the right approach? Can someone help me with &rand() and how to get the random element added to the loop here?

Answer (score 4):

You could,

```
for (1 .. 10000) {
  my $rand = int rand 10000;
  print "abc -s $rand\n";
}
```

or use one liner,

```
perl -E 'say "abc -s ", int rand 10000 for 1..10000' > file.txt
```